# Change batch size using a list of Pytorch's data loader

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader, batchsize

During the training of my neural network model, I used a Pytorch's data loader to accelerate the training of the model. But instead of using a fixed batch size before updating the model's parameter, I have a list of different batch sizes that I want the data loader to use.

Example

```
train_dataset = TensorDataset(x_train, y_train) # x_train.shape (8400, 4)
dataloader_train = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=64) # with fixed batch size of 64
```

What I want is a data loader that can use a list of batch size that is dynamic (not fixe)?

```
list_batch_size = [30, 60, 110, ..., 231] # with this list's sum being equal to x_train.shape[0] (8400)
```

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloader-for-variable-batch-size/13840/13)?

Comment: My last comment on @heemayl's answer was addressed here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77667732/12775432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom sampler (or batch sampler) for this.

Here's a quick *proof-of-concept* for a sampler that takes custom batch sizes as an argument to return batch indices as such:

```
class VariableBatchSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, dataset_len: int, batch_sizes: list):
        self.dataset_len = dataset_len
        self.batch_sizes = batch_sizes
        self.batch_idx = 0
        self.start_idx = 0
        self.end_idx = self.batch_sizes[self.batch_idx]
        
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
       
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start_idx >= self.dataset_len:
            raise StopIteration()
 
        batch_indices = torch.arange(self.start_idx, self.end_idx, dtype=torch.int)
        self.start_idx += (self.end_idx - self.start_idx)
        self.batch_idx += 1

        try:
            self.end_idx += self.batch_sizes[self.batch_idx]
        except IndexError:
            self.end_idx = self.dataset_len
             
        return batch_indices
```

You can instantiate the sampler and use it as the `sampler` argument while instantiating the `DataLoader` e.g.:

```
sampler = VariableBatchSampler(dataset_len=len(train_dataset), batch_sizes=[10, 20, 30, 40])
data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, sampler=sampler)
```

Note that, each element in the `data_loader` iterable would contain one extra dimension for the batch (as the default value for `batch_size` is 1 in `DataLoader`); you can either use `unsqueeze(dim=0)` to get rid of the extra dim. Or better pass the sampler as the `batch_sampler` argument:

```
data_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_sampler=sampler)
```

Comment: There was this error `IndexError: tensors used as indices must be long, byte or bool tensors` in your code when I tried it on my use case so I changed the `batch_indices dtype for int to long`

Comment: @pyaj Interesting. `int` works fine on my Python 3.11 with `torch` version `2.0.1+cu117`.

Comment: That's quite awkward I have Python 3.6.13 and Torch 1.10.2

Comment: Hi @heemayl, I have noticed in your solution that I can't loop your custom sampler into the dataloader. It only works for one epoch.